# time data doesn't match format specified

Tags: python-datetime

I am trying to convert the string to the type of 'datetime' in python. My data match the format, but still get the 
'ValueError: time data 11 11 doesn't match format specified'
I am not sure where does the "11 11" in the error come from.

My code is

```
train_df['date_captured1'] = pd.to_datetime(train_df['date_captured'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Head of data is

```
print (train_df.date_captured.head())

0    2011-05-13 23:43:18
1    2012-03-17 03:48:44
2    2014-05-11 11:56:46
3    2013-10-06 02:00:00
4    2011-07-12 13:11:16
Name: date_captured, dtype: object
```

I tried the following by just selecting the first string and running the code with same datetime format. They all work without problem.

```
dt=train_df['date_captured']
dt1=dt[0]
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(date)

2011-05-13 23:43:18
```

and

```
dt1=pd.to_datetime(dt1, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print (dt1)

2011-05-13 23:43:18
```

But why wen I using the same format in pd.to_datetime to convert all the data in the column, it comes up with the error above?
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like the error is from line 2 where your date is `2014-05-11 11:56:46` this has the `11 11` do you have anymore information?

Comment: I solved it! It's not the line 2. But I found in line 100372, the date_captured value is '11 11'.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

```
train_df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(train_df['date_captured'], errors='coerce')
print (train_df[train_df.date_time.isnull()])
```

I found in line 100372, the date_captured value is '11 11'

```
        category_id date_captured    ...     height  date_time
100372           10         11 11    ...        747        NaT
```

So the code with `errors='coerce'` will replace the invalid parsing with NaN.
Thank you.